# Concise form of "remove from the list" and "add to the list" in the same sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I a technical correspondence, I wanted to express the fact that there are two outcomes of "onclick" event:

> Also, "onclick" event removes the group in question from the list "excluded_groups" or adds it to the list.

However, the above sentence looks too long to me. Is the following sentence grammatically and stylistically correct: (note that there is no "from" after "remove", or anywhere else in the sentence)

> Also, "onclick" event removes or adds the group in question to the list "excluded_groups".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following is the best solution:
'Also, "onclick" event removes the group in question from or adds it to the list.'

Answer (score 1):

> Also, "onclick" event toggles the group in question on or off the "excluded_groups" list.

*toggle*

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toggle#Verb

1. to alternate between two positions using a single switch or lever.
   *Clicking a button will alternately toggle its light on OR off.*
2. to switch between alternate states.
   *toggle to lower/upper case*
   *You can quickly toggle the case of selected text by pressing Shift+C*